# Dynamically enabling a graphics driver during run time

Tags: api, graphics, driver, gdi

Is it possible to change the active graphics driver in the middle of execution of a program? Or does it require a reboot or re-login?

If so, what sort of API calls (ChangeDisplaySettings?) would I use to dynamically activate and  deactivate the driver. Do I need to install the new driver first and reboot, or can that be done dynamically as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that ChangeDisplaySettings() is exactly what I need to do this with a mirror driver.